# Automation the import of files to Database

Tags: machine-learning, automation

I don't know if this it's possible but nowadays as almost everything is possible I am asking to see if anyone has any idea.

The problem is:

> Regularly I have to import files (CSV, XML, Excel, ...) to an SQL Server Database and after I import the files I have to map the content of the columns of the imported files in a .sql Script to run and insert in a table in another DB (this table is the same for all the files imported).
>
> I spend a lot of time on these mappings as you can imagine, I want to know if it's possible through Artificial Intelligence or Machine Learning one solution that can make the import of the initial data to the final DB, the initial import I can make it automatically the problem is only the import of the imported files to the final DB.
>
> **Note**: The initial files don't have the same columns names, each file can have different columns names.

Sorry for the long post but I don't know if it is possible something like that. I searched and don't find anything.